# Не изменяется цена Bitrix "Bitrix\Catalog\Model\Price::update"

Tags: битрикс

Всем привет!

Была поставлена задача, сделать синхронизацию цен и остатков товаров с api производителя

Для обновления цены использую вот такой код

```
 $arFieldsPrice = Array(
                                "PRODUCT_ID" => $ID,                            //ID добавленного товара
                                "CATALOG_GROUP_ID" => 1,                        //ID типа цены
                                "PRICE" => $price_rozn,                     //значение цены
                                "CURRENCY" => !$currency ? "RUB" : $currency,   // валюта
                            );
                            
                            //Смотрим установлена ли цена адля данного товара
                            $dbPrice = \Bitrix\Catalog\Model\Price::getList([
                                "filter" => array(
                                    "PRODUCT_ID" => $ID,
                                    "CATALOG_GROUP_ID" => 1
                                )
                            ]);
                            
                            if ($arPrice = $dbPrice->fetch()) {
                                //Если цена установлена, то обновляем
                                $result = \Bitrix\Catalog\Model\Price::update($arPrice["ID"], $arFieldsPrice, true);
                                
                                if ($result->isSuccess()){
                                    echo "Обновили цену у товара у элемента каталога " . $ID . " Цена " . $price_rozn . PHP_EOL;
                                } else {
                                    echo "Ошибка обновления цены у товара у элемента каталога " . $ID . " Ошибка " . $result->getErrorMessages() . PHP_EOL;
                                }
                            }else{
                                //Если цены нет, то добавляем
                                $result = \Bitrix\Catalog\Model\Price::add($arFieldsPrice, true);
                                
                                if ($result->isSuccess()){
                                    echo "Добавили цену у товара у элемента каталога " . $ID . " Цена " . $price_rozn . PHP_EOL;
                                } else {
                                    echo "Ошибка добавления цены у товара у элемента каталога " . $ID . " Ошибка " . $result->getErrorMessages() . PHP_EOL;
                                }
                            }
```

Цены обновились, но цена в корзине стала 0... Пробовал CIBlock::clearIblockTagCache() не помогло, так же сбрасывая кеш ничего не происходит.

Кто нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так

```
$obPrice = new CPrice;
            // обновляем цены
            $arFieldsForPrice = [
                "PRODUCT_ID"       => $elementId, // id именно элемента, а не торгового предложения
                "CATALOG_GROUP_ID" => 1,
                "PRICE"            => $arElement["#"]["price"][0]["#"],
                "CURRENCY"         => "RUB",
            ];
            $resPrice = $obPrice->GetList([], ["PRODUCT_ID" => $elementId, "CATALOG_GROUP_ID" => 1]);
            if ($arPrice = $resPrice->Fetch()) {
                pre($arPrice);
                $obPrice->Update($arPrice["ID"], $arFieldsForPrice);
            } else {
                $obPrice->Add($arFieldsForPrice);
            }
```